# Get photo from Salesforce after authentication

Tags: objective-c, ios4, salesforce

I'm using the ZKSforce library to connect to Salesforce with OAuth.

I run the following query which returns the proper values:

```
Select Id, Name, Username, Email, Phone, Division, FullPhotoUrl from User
```

I send try to download the FullPhotoUrl from the path (which is correct) the following way using API 21, but I get null...

```
UIImage * img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
        [NSURL URLWithString:[(ZKSObject*)[records objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
        fieldValue:@"FullPhotoUrl"]]]];
```

Do you know how I could download the FullPhotoUrl from Salesforce once I have made a successful connection?

Tia,

S.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the oauth token or sessionId to the url to authenticate the request, add `?oauth_token=<insert valid session id/OAuth token>` to the URL, see this [blog post](http://blog.sforce.com/sforce/2011/03/accessing-chatter-user-pics.html) for more info.

There's a `sessionId` property on the ZKSforceClient object you can use to access the current sessionId.

Also, I can't remember if the FullPhotoUrl returns an absolute or relative URL, if its relative, you're going to need to build an absolute version of the URL first.